# Mysql complex query to join

Tags: php, mysql, join

I need some help to JOIN the queries below, because I believe this is super heavy, While loops inside other while loops... a mess, right?! :(

This works, but if someone could help to JOIN this into one query only:

```
$query_1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM booking_reservation WHERE reservation_confirmed = '1' AND (reservation_name LIKE '$data%' OR reservation_phone LIKE '$data%' OR reservation_email LIKE '$data%')");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_1)) {
        $calendar_id = $row['calendar_id'];
        $query_2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM booking_calendars WHERE calendar_id = '$calendar_id'");
        $row_2 = mysql_fetch_array($query_2);
        $slot_id = $query_1['slot_id'];
        $query_3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM booking_slots WHERE slot_id = '$slot_id'");
        while ($row_3 = mysql_fetch_array($query_3)) {
            echo '<tr><td>' . htmlentities($row2['slot_date']) . '</td><td>' . htmlentities($query_3['slot_time_from']) . '</td><td>' .  htmlentities($query_1['reservation_name']) . '</td><td>' .  htmlentities($query_3['calendar_title']) . '</td><td>' . htmlentities($query_1['reservation_phone']) . '</td><td>' . htmlentities($query_1['reservation_email']) . '</td></tr>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions, use PDO / MySQLi instead.

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The question seems to be on-topic (unfortunately).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of these should be what you want, you use `INNER JOIN` if you want to get reservations that only exist in booking_calendars, and booking_slots, or `LEFT JOIN` if you want all reservations regardless if they exist in the other tables

Inner join:

```
SELECT * FROM booking_reservation br 
INNER JOIN booking_calendars bc ON br.calendar_id=bc.calendar_id 
INNER JOIN booking_slots bs ON br.slot_id=bs.slot_id 
WHERE br.reservation_confirmed = '1' 
AND (br.reservation_name LIKE '$data%' 
OR br.reservation_phone LIKE '$data%' 
OR br.reservation_email LIKE '$data%')
```

Left join:

```
SELECT * FROM booking_reservation br 
LEFT JOIN booking_calendars bc ON br.calendar_id=bc.calendar_id 
LEFT JOIN booking_slots bs ON br.slot_id=bs.slot_id 
WHERE br.reservation_confirmed = '1' 
AND (br.reservation_name LIKE '$data%' 
OR br.reservation_phone LIKE '$data%' 
OR br.reservation_email LIKE '$data%')
```

1 important note, using `SELECT *` isn't recommended, it is much better to tell mysql which columns you need from each of the tables, or from the table you're selecting from.

**N.B.: You should listen to what Raptor said, mysql_* functions are deprecated and will be removed in later php versions, you should start using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli)**

Answer (score 0):

Try with this i hope this query will works for you

```
select * from booking_reservation br  
join booking_calendars bc ON br.calendar_id=bc.calendar_id 
join booking_slots bs ON bc.slot_id=bs.slot_id
where br.reservation_confirmed='1' 
AND br.(reservation_name LIKE '$data%' OR br.reservation_phone LIKE '$data%' OR br.reservation_email LIKE '$data%')
```

Comment: Comma-separated joins where replaced with explicit joins in standard SQL more than twenty years ago. They shouldn't be used anymore.

Comment: @ Thorsten Kettner i hope you feel happy......actually with the past query i didn't see difference in the performance...so i went that query

Comment: I am happy, thank you :-) It's not about performance, however; the queries are equivalent. It's about readability and error-proneness (with comma-separated joins one can not distinguish desired and undesired cross-joins for instance).